# margin: auto doesn't center?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div on the document, and it works horizontally, but not vertically:

```
width: 950px;
height: 630px;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: auto;
```

Shouldn't `margin: auto` place it in the center of whatever it's in (the page itself, in this case)? I used to have a workaround for this, but I can't get it to work. It would also be nice to know what I'm doing wrong, so I can stop doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`margin: auto` does not align elements vertically.

If you have to support older browsers, you'll have to define a fixed height for your div:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px; /* sample. adjust as needed */
    margin: -250px auto 0; /* half the height */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2qmVX/

---

If you don't care about IE8 and below, this'll allow you to retain your fluid height:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* add prefixed versions... */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VMaVM/ (remember: modern browsers only).

---

**Update:** As pointed out by @FabrícioMatté, you also have to apply 100% height to the `html` & `body` elements:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

See the demos above.

Comment: Don't forget to add that if you don't give 100% width and height to the html and body elements this will most likely not work.

Comment: +1 for the `translateY`, wasn't aware that it could be used for this. In a layman's terms, it's a more modern way of giving a negative margin without having to set a fixed value? I'll find some use for it on the next responsive design I make.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - The `html` & `body` elements are block level elements, and are automatically rendered with `width: 100%`. As for their height: you're most definitely right, and I have them set up that way in the fiddles. Added a note to the answer above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up as well, one less line from my CSS normalization code by removing the `width:100%` `=]`

Comment: There's still one issue with both approaches, that is, if the window height is lower than the `div`'s height, the `div` will be pushed up outside of the viewport and it is not possible to scroll up to see the first line. Guess that can't be easily solved.

Answer (score 3):

Proper vertical centering is something that not even CSS3 covers yet.

Luckily in your case, as you have a fixed height, you can maneuver the `top`/`left` properties and use negative `margin-top` and `margin-left` to attain the desired behavior, with `absolute` positioning:

```
background: #FFFFFF;
width: 950px;
height: 630px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -315px 0 0 -425px; /*top is negative half of height, same for width*/
position: absolute;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d2CpS/4/show/) / [source](http://jsfiddle.net/d2CpS/4/)

Beware that negative margins may behave unexpectedly on resolutions smaller than the `div`.

---

Here's a slightly more hackish way, using a table. The basic idea is that the `vertical-align:middle` CSS property when applied to a table has the same effect as the old `valign="center"` attribute. So the HTML would looks like this:

```
<table class="vcenter"><tr><td>
    <div id="myDiv">This is a centered div</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.vcenter {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#myDiv {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 950px;
    height: 630px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sMd34/show/) / [source](http://jsfiddle.net/sMd34/)

Advantages of this method is that it is completely cross-browser - tested on IE6 and up, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. I didn't test on mobile browsers though it should work. Also it doesn't have the scrolling issue with small resolutions. I use this hack for centered modals in one of my production sites.